# Search PHP - how to bring up search box with no results

Tags: php, search

I have 6 items in my test database. The search box is located at http://vince.netau.net    All of the 6 items in the database show up before I even search for anything in the search box.  What do I have to change in the code so that just the search box shows up without any results?  Thanks

```
<?php
define("ROW_PER_PAGE",2);
require_once('db.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{width:615px;font-family:arial;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:20px;}
.tbl-qa{width: 100%;font-size:0.9em;background-color: #f5f5f5;}
.tbl-qa th.table-header {padding: 5px;text-align: left;padding:10px;}
.tbl-qa .table-row td {padding:10px;background-color: #FDFDFD;vertical-align:top;}
.button_link {color:#FFF;text-decoration:none; background-color:#428a8e;padding:10px;}
#keyword{border: #CCC 1px solid; border-radius: 4px; padding: 7px;background:url("demo-search-icon.png") no-repeat center right 7px;}
.btn-page{margin-right:10px;padding:5px 10px; border: #CCC 1px solid; background:#FFF; border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer;}
.btn-page:hover{background:#F0F0F0;}
.btn-page.current{background:#F0F0F0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
    $search_keyword = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :keyword OR description LIKE :keyword OR post_at LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id DESC ';

    /* Pagination Code starts */
    $per_page_html = '';
    $page = 1;
    $start=0;
    if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
        $page = $_POST["page"];
        $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
    }
    $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
    $pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
    $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pagination_statement->execute();

    $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
    if(!empty($row_count)){
        $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
        $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
        if($page_count>1) {
            for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                if($i==$page){
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
                } else {
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
                }
            }
        }
        $per_page_html .= "</div>";
    }

    $query = $sql.$limit;
    $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
?>
<form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
<div style='text-align:right;margin:20px 0px;'><input type='text' name='search[keyword]' value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword' maxlength='25'></div>
<table class='tbl-qa'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Title</th>
      <th class='table-header' width='40%'>Description</th>
      <th class='table-header' width='20%'>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='table-body'>
    <?php
    if(!empty($result)) { 
        foreach($result as $row) {
    ?>
      <tr class='table-row'>
        <td><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>"
                <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_at']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am I supposed to change this block of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify Chip's answer.. You just need to make your first IF control all of your search and display code...

```
   $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
   }  <<  remove this closing curly bracket

  and put it here
    .......
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
 }  // END if $_POST['search']['keyword']  is !empty
 ?>
```

Comment: Really confused.  Was I supposed to change the 3 lines of code I had into the 1 line you provided and remove the curly bracket and put it before $result = $pdo_statement-> fetchAll();   If so it gave me an error?

Comment: moving one '} '  in your code from the question,  otherwise your code is identical..   Move the one under ` $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];` to be below ` $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to move all of your database php code into that first if statement. You are checking to see if the form has been submitted but then you run the query anyway. By moving all the code into that if statement you will prevent the query from running unless the form was actually submitted. You are already checking if your results are empty so having results be undefined is ok.

```
$search_keyword = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :keyword OR description LIKE :keyword OR post_at LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id DESC ';

    /* Pagination Code starts */
    $per_page_html = '';
    $page = 1;
    $start=0;
    if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
        $page = $_POST["page"];
        $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
    }
    $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
    $pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
    $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pagination_statement->execute();

    $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
    if(!empty($row_count)){
        $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
        $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
        if($page_count>1) {
            for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                if($i==$page){
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
                } else {
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
                }
            }
        }
        $per_page_html .= "</div>";
    }

    $query = $sql.$limit;
    $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: Newbie here so not exactly sure what you mean.  This is all I have in my db.php                                                                                                 <?php
 $database_username = '';
 $database_password = '';
 $pdo_conn = new PDO( ';dbname=', $, $ );
?>